# QueryDSL re-uses table alias for sub-query

Tags: java, querydsl

I'm having the following simple query:

```
return new JPAQuery<Job>().from(job)
    .where(job.container.id.eq(cid)
        .and(job.levels.any().in(levels)))
    .fetch();
```

`cid` is of type `Long`, `levels` is a list of entities.

QueryDSL generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT t0.x, t0.y, t0.z
FROM job t0 
WHERE (((t0.id = 19) 
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM job t0 
          JOIN (job_level_mapping t3 
           JOIN level t2 ON (t2.id = t3.level_id)) ON (t3.job_id = t0.id),
        level t1 
        WHERE ((t1.id IN (74,77)) AND (t2.id = t1.id)))) 
    AND (t0.job_type = 'SUBMIT'));
```

Note that the table alias `t0` for table `job` is the same for the main query and sub-query. This leads to a wrong query result. If I manually rename the alias from the outer `FROM` from `t0` to `tx` and also change `(t3.job_id = t0.id)` inside the sub-query to `(t3.job_id = tx.id)`, then the query works as expected.

Is there some way to tell QueryDSL to use different table aliases for the main query and sub-query? Or is there a different way to write this query?

I'm using QueryDSL 4.1.4.

EDIT:
I'm now using the `EntityManager` directly with a JPA query and this is
working:

```
return getEm().createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT job FROM " +
    "Job job " +
     "WHERE job.container.id = :cid AND job.jobType = :jobType AND job.levels IN :levels", Job.class)
     .setParameter("jobType", JobType.SUBMIT)
     .setParameter("cid", cId)
     .setParameter("levels", levels)
     .getResultList();
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT t0.x, t0.y, t0.z 
FROM job t0 
    JOIN (job_level_mapping t2 
    JOIN level t1 ON (t1.id = t2.level_id)) ON (t2.job_id = t0.id) 
WHERE (((t0.cid = ?) AND (t0.job_type = ?)) AND (t1.id IN (?,?)));
```

Comment: I doubt that it is QueryDSL that is generating the aliases. Perhaps this is an issue in Hibernate. Could you provide the generated JPQL query?

Comment: Oh, I should've mentioned that we are using EclipseLink / Payara / Java EE. How can I print out the JPQL query? Currently I can only log the actual SQL query shown in the question.

Comment: Try:

```

        JPQLSerializer jpqlSerializer = new JPQLSerializer(EclipseLinkTemplates.DEFAULT);
        jpqlSerializer.serialize(query.getMetadata(), false, null);
        String query = jpqlSerializer.toString();
```